# Growth Book Now Supports ClickHouse - need the installation process for ubuntu server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I have a Growthbook that has already mogo DB integrated and I want to change the database click house because it is fast. please let me know the process of installation of my own domain and also how to create DB and user in click house database?
Github link: https://github.com/growthbook/growthbook
Those are the command not working to create DB and user in click house DB.

```
CREATE DATABASE wordpress_db;
CREATE USER 'wp_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON wordpress_db.* TO 'wp_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one place in GrowthBook's GitHub where it says that ClickHouse is supported, and others where it says that the work to integrate with ClickHouse is not complete.  This is a very recent issue that says it is not integrated yet:
https://github.com/growthbook/growthbook/issues/371